# Como enviar dados SQL com dados pre definidos em PHP

Tags: php

Usando uma estrutura de repetição `while` eu quero enviar dados predefinidos.
Vou tentar mostrar.

Banco de dados:
nome:(joao,gabriel,vitor)
modo:(0,0,0)

### pagina1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>

<?php 
$sql = $db->query("SELECT nome,modo FROM banco_de_dados");
?>

<?php
while($dados = $sql->fetch_array()){
    $nome = $dados['nome'];
    $modo = $dados['modo'];

    $_SESSION['nome_id'.$num] = $nome;
    $num++;

?>
<center>
NOME: <?php  
echo $nome;
?> |
<?php  
echo $modo;
?> |
<a href="pagina2.php" role="button">ON//OFF</a><br>
</center>


<?php
}
?>
```

### pagina2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'pagina1.php';

$sql_up = "UPDATE bando_de_dados SET modo = ('1') WHERE nome = '$nome'" ;
$up = mysqli_query($db, $sql_up);

?>
```

[image: IMAGEM - EXEMPLO]

Ao clicar em `on//off`, muda de `0` para `1`.(Vai mudar de 1 por 1, de acordo com o clique)

Comment: Como assim dados predifinidos?

Comment: Me parece que ele quer saber como enviar um parâmetro para a `pagina2.php`

Comment: exemplo: 
nome:(joao,gabriel,vitor)
modo:(0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Você deve passar como parâmetro na `pagina1.php` os valores que você deseja passar como parâmetro para `página2.php`.

```
<center>
 NOME: <?php echo $nome; ?> | <?php echo $modo; ?> | <a href="pagina2.php?nome=<?= $nome ?>&modo=<?= $modo ?>" role="button">ON//OFF</a><br> 
</center>
```

Na `página2.php` você lerá essas variáveis e usará no seu SQL da seguinte forma.

```
$nome = $_GET('nome');
$modo = $_GET('modo');
```

Existem outras formas de fazer, mas isso atende sua necessidade.